# I am searching Gmail for a ticket # and that pulls up related emails. How can I search for a specific string within those emails that appear?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, search

I am writing code in Google Apps Script to search for a string in emails that appear when I search for a specific ticket number related to insurance claims. I have written code so far that takes a cell with a ticket number from a Google spreadsheet, searches that number in Gmail and returns any related emails to the spreadsheet to another column, "total amount reimbursed" on the ticket number's row. Then, it takes the date of the email and puts it in the "reimbursement date" column.

My problem is that I can't figure out how to do a search within a search. In other words, I need to search for the following text when the emails related to the ticket number are pulled up: "reimbursed your account X for...". Then, I need the code to pull the amount from the string (X) and put it in the "total amount reimbursed" column. When I run the code, it puts the entire email found related to the ticket number in the "total amount reimbursed" column.

Here is my code:

```
function searchGmail(){
var value = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Tickets/Tolls Reimbursements 
Master').getRange(8686,12).getValue();

if(value.length > 0)

var threads=GmailApp.search(value);

var myspreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1Jn7r4...");
var mysheet = myspreadsheet.getSheets()[0];
var threads = GmailApp.search(value);;
var messages = GmailApp.getMessagesForThreads(threads); 
var body = [];
var date = [];

for(var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++)
{
body.push([messages[i][0].getPlainBody(),i]);
}
mysheet.getRange(8686,19,threads.length,2).setValues(body);

for(var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++)
{
date.push([messages[i][0].getDate(),i]);
}
mysheet.getRange(8686,20,threads.length,2).setValues(date);

}
```

I would greatly appreciate any help here. I am new to coding and JavaScript, and I am really stuck.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like the code below.  I use a regular expression to find the phrase you are looking for then the number that immediately follows the search phrase. I believe you can write the regular expression to exclude the search string from the results and just return the number, but I've never been very good with RegEx so, instead, I split the string up by each word and then grab the last word, which is the number, represented by X in your question. That should hopefully give you a start to figure out how you'd like to solve it.

```
for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {

  // creates a regular expressiom that finds the phrase "reimbursed your account" and number that immedatly follows it
  let regExp = new RegExp('reimbursed your account [0-9]+');

  // assign the message text to a variable
  let message = messages[i][0].getPlainBody();

  // executes the regular expression on the message variable and stores the results in a new array called phrase
  let phrase = regExp.exec(message);

  // I assume the search phrase will only apprear once in the email. If appears more than once, you'll need to loop through pharse and deal with each instance appropriately.
  // split the string into an array at every space in the string, pop off the last value (the number) and store it in num variable
  let num = phrase[0].split(" ").pop()

  body.push([num, I]);
}
mysheet.getRange(8686, 19, threads.length, 2).setValues(body);
```

Comment: Thank you @Tyler Baker!

Comment: let num = phrase[0].split(" ").pop() this line is producing an error. It says TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null. Do you know why that is happening?

Comment: I'm guessing your email search results return the entire email thread where any of the messages match on your search value, then you are executing the RegEx on each message. Some of which won't have the phrase you are looking for. So the RegEx results will be null. Then you are trying to split the first index value but the value is null.  Try surrounding let num and body.push in `if (phrase){ code here}`. Or use a try catch to run the code and log any errors to the logs.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I'll try that.

Comment: Everything is working now except one line: mysheet.getRange(8686,19,threads.length,2).setValues(body);

It's producing this error: 
Exception: The number of rows in the data does not match the number of rows in the range. The data has 0 but the range has 2.

Do you know how I can fix that?

Comment: Well, now it sounds like nothing was actually being found from RegEx. So nothing ever get's pushed into body. there for body.length is 0. You might try setting a breakpoint at `mysheet.getRange(8686, 19, threads.length, 2).setValues(body);` and looking at the contents of body just before you try and set the values. Also, you could add a `Logger.log (phrase);` right after `let phrase = regExp.exec(message);`. My guess is you won't see any value for the entire loop. In which case, you'll have to do some investigating on your RegEx criteria.

Comment: Try copying a message into an online RegEx editor and make sure the expression you are using in your code is capturing what you are expecting it to.

Comment: You can direct message me on Google chat if you'd like. tyler@pinnaclepowersvcs.com

Comment: Thank you! I probably do have to check my RegEx, because I'm not good at writing those. But, I realized that I'm trying to pull a number from a screenshot. The text is inside an image in the email. Do you think there is a way to convert the image to html so I can look at the text inside it? I think that's why the body.length is 0. I'll direct message you.

Comment: Not simply. You'd have to extract the image from the email and send it off to an image to text API then evaluate the results. You can read more about it here: `https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/ocr#vision_text_detection_gcs-drest`

Comment: I figured that would require OCR. Thank you for all your help! I've had to deal with other, more important projects this week, but I'll try out your suggestion when I get back to this.